# Tell me a fix for ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR in Node.js, mysql crud operation

Tags: node.js, mysql-workbench, crud

I am an absolute novice at Node.js. So, as I'm learning, I ran into this problem.
I am adding codes from backend for CRUD (This index.js may seem incomplete, because I faced the problem halfway and then started seeking the solution.)

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

### index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mysql from "mysql";

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "akdkfjdkfj;a",
    database: "online_sustainability_db"
});

app.use(express.json());   

app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.json("Hello. You are connected to backend.");
});

app.get("/data", (req, res) =>{
    const query = "SELECT * FROM online_sustainability_db.idea_proposers";
    db.query(query, (err, data)=>{
        if(err)
            return res.json(err);
        else 
            return res.json(data);
    })
});

app.post("/data", (req, res)=>{
    const q = "INSERT INTO idea_proposers (`last_name`, `first_name`, `account_no`, `github_repository_link`, `submission_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    const last_name = req.body.last_name;
    const first_name = req.body.first_name; 
    const account_no = req.body.account_no; 
    const github_link = req.body.github_repository_link; 
    const submission_id = req.body.submission_id;
    
    
    db.query(q, [last_name, first_name, account_no, github_link, submission_id], (err, data)=>{
        if(err)
            return res.json(err);
        else 
            return res.json("Provided data were recorded successfully.");
    });
});

app.listen(8800, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to backend!");
});
```

The following image is from postman application. This is the error I am getting. Please, help me fixing it.
[image]

This is the description of the table I am trying to post the data in.
[image]

I tried doing some syntactical change and running the code several times. Well, it didn't work. I even looked for resources online, but I couldn't find any similar.

Comment: `account_no` cannot be `NULL` as it is set to `NOT NULL`. In your server code, `req.body.account_no` is probably `undefined` because `req.body` is a string or a buffer. This is because you are sending a text body in Postman and not a JSON body. For the future, it's important to learn systematic troubleshooting. You can trace the unexpected behavior back to its source step by step, verifying your assumptions about behavior or values on every step, then you'd find the problem yourself or you'd ask about a more specific question such as "why is `req.body` a string when I'm sending JSON".

Answer (score 1):

Kindly select the `JSON` from Postman whenever you want to send the JSON data. currently, you're sending data as a `text`.